# How do I connect to external mysql database on heroku?

Tags: php, mysql, database, heroku

I created a FB app hosted on Heroku.

Instead of Heroku's database I use a mysql database. I made the chage using this code:

```
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:pass@server:port/database_name
```

So far everything is ok but now I have an issue connecting to the database in my index.php file.

I don't know ho to do.

I tried to connect to the DB as I do on my website

```
try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=database_name', 'user', 'pass');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

But I have an error in my app:

> Application Error
>   An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your remote database port is opened for external connection. Look for bind-address configuration of your remote mysql server.